# Inclusion of typeclasses with default implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Consider the following definitions:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> Int

class Bar a where
    bar :: a -> [Int]
```

Now, how do I say *"every `Foo` is also a `Bar`, with `bar` defined by default as `bar x = [foo x]`"* in Haskell?

(Whatever I try, the compiler gives me *"Illegal instance declaration"* or *"Constraint is no smaller than the instance head"*)

Btw, I can define my `Foo` and `Bar` classes in some other way, if this would help.

Comment: This is related to (duplicate of?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213490/how-do-i-write-if-typeclass-a-then-a-is-also-an-instance-of-b-by-this-definiti/3214201#3214201

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the automatic definition of a `Bar` instance through a `Foo` instance can lead to undecidable cases for the compiler - i.e. one explicit instance and one through `Foo` conflicting with each other - , we need some special options to allow the desired behaviour. The rest through is quite straigtforward.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> Int

class Bar a where
    bar :: a -> [Int]

instance (Foo a) => Bar a where
    bar x = [foo x]
```

Comment: If you plan to have any more instances of `Bar` (and doing this is pointless without), then you need `OverlappingInstances` too.  This causes type inference to have weird results sometimes (always use signatures when talking about these classes), and is generally a sign that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: And never publish a module with such an instance in it. It is rude (it causes wicked modularity problems).  Always prefer max taldykin's solution if you plan on sharing.

Comment: Really, you just shouldn't do this.  Even if you don't publish it, you'll most likely have other subtle problems.

Answer (score 12):

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> Int

-- 'a' belongs to 'Bar' only if it belongs to 'Foo' also
class Foo a => Bar a where
    bar :: a -> [Int]
    bar x = [foo x] -- yes, you can specify default implementation

instance Foo Char where
    foo _ = 0

-- instance with default 'bar' implementation
instance Bar Char
```

Comment: This is much friendlier in terms of modularity than the `instance Foo a => Bar a` solution.

Comment: But shouldn't author's requirement of "every Foo is also a Bar" be expressed with 'class Bar a => Foo a where' not vice versa like here?

Comment: But it looks to me that m01 actually meant 'class Foo a => Bar' a where' or otherwise it doesn't make sense to define bar via foo

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking you don't model things with type classes this way[*] - i.e. an instance of a type class should always be some concrete type, though that type itself can be parameteric - e.g. the Show instance for pair has this signature:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a,b) where
```

Some of the approaches to "Generics" allow you to model a general base case and then have type specific exceptional cases. SYB3 allowed this - perhaps unfortunately SYB3 isn't the common practice Generics library it is Data.Data / Data.Generics which I think is SYB1.

[*] In the wild the story is a little more complicated - as Dario says UndecidableInstances can enable it.