# Why is this declaration not allowed in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know that `Functor` and `Applicative` should be superclasses of `Monad`, but aren't for historical reasons. However, why isn't is possible to declare `Monad` an instance of `Functor`? This would have roughly the same effect, but without having to modify existing code. If you're trying to do this, GHC complains:

```
instance Functor Monad where
   fmap = liftM

Class `Monad' used as a type
In the instance declaration for `Functor Monad'
```

Why is that? There's probably a good reason for it.

Comment: How about `instance (Monad m) => Functor m`?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213490/how-do-i-write-if-typeclass-a-then-a-is-also-an-instance-of-b-by-this-definiti/3216937#3216937

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. `Monad` is a typeclass, not a data type. What you could write is

```
instance Monad a => Functor a where fmap = liftM
```

However, this will only work with the extensions `FlexibleInstances` (permits instances that are not of the form `T a1 a2 ... an` where `a1, a2, ... an` are type variables and there is no context) and `UndecidableInstances` (which permits this specific instance [I don't know why this is needed]).

Comment: `UndecidableInstances` is needed because the declaration conflicts with every monad that's explicitly defined to be a functor, including all the monads in the standard library.

Comment: Well, I guess the `UndecidableInstances` requirement also answers the question why this isn't being defined in Prelude or another package...

Comment: @dave4420 The compiler says, that the reason for that is something about that the instance head is bigger than the instance itself... I didn't understood it. Additionally, there is a proposal to change the definition of monads to include functors and applicative.

Comment: Note also that in general, I believe that these types of instances prevent you from writing any other `Functor` instances after that declaration.

Comment: dave4420 is incorrect: conflicting declarations would imply `OverlappingInstances` or `IncoherentInstances`. The reason this requires `UndecidableInstances` is the following: when checking whether `Foo` is a `Functor`, this rule implies that we must then check that `Foo` is a `Monad` -- that is, we must recurse into the instance-finding algorithm with a type that is _not_ smaller than the one we started with. If we allow such recursion, it's easy to write instances that never stop recursing, whereas if the type must get smaller at each step it is obviously impossible.

Comment: Imagine if one then also defined `instance Functor a => Monad a` (never mind that you couldn't define any of the methods, the typechecker doesn't know that). `UndecidableInstances` is you telling GHC "I didn't do anything stupid like the above, trust me".

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Monad` is a type class while an instance declaration requires a type or type constructor. The error message clearly states that. Type classes and type are two distinct kinds of things. They are never interchangable in Haskell.