# output a value in Haskell, with a default in case its type is not an instance of Show

Tags: debugging, haskell

I tried to debug some Arrows and this is really hard. I end up sticking `trace` here and there, but it really wants a `Show` instance as its argument, which limits its uses. Is there any way to `show` something if it is an instance of Show, and use some kind of a default output value if it's not? I promise to use that only for debugging ;-)

How do people debug Arrows anyway...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use the default"? If you have some sort of function of type `Foo -> String`, you can always apply that to your argument before tracing it.

Comment: I have a function kind of like `arr f = SF f :: (a -> b) -> arr a b`, and I want to stick a `trace` in it to inspect `a`'s, but they are not always of `Show` so I get a type error.

Comment: What do you want to happen if they aren't of Show? Just tracing the empty string?

Comment: yeah, or some kind of a default value, or maybe a type of the expression

Comment: step 1) Implement instance chains in GHC 2) Create a new class 3) Instantiate the class as `instance (Show a) => NewShow a where newShow = show ; instance otherwise where newShow = const "not an instance"` 4) Profit.

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler's aversion to [multiple instance declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015009/fun-with-types-resolving-multiple-instance-declarations) I suspect makes Thomas's approach a bit tricky.

Comment: @leftaroundabout apparently it is, thank you! Voted for closing it

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thought about that, yeah; spent some time on Hackage after that, thinking somebody has created a trace module with this already

Comment: Have you tried using the debug features built in to ghci?  They're a bit clunky to use (and line-by-line debugging has less meaning in haskell than in a procedural language), but it can be useful.

Comment: To get the type, you could turn on `FlexibleInstances`, `OverlappingInstances`, and `UndecidableInstances`, import `Data.Typeable`, and declare `instance Typeable a => Show a where show = show . typeOf`. This is a terrible hack, and you might have to derive `Typeable` (via `DeriveDataTypeable`) for some of your own types, but you did promise ...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just compose trace into your arrow:

```
strace x = trace (show x) x

something :: (Num c, Show c, Arrow cat) => cat c c
something = arr (+1) <<< arr strace

-- > something 1
-- 1
-- 2
```

Comment: thank you, I did that, but the problem I'm debugging is too hard even with this :( I think I'll try asking on SO about it later