# Type instances in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Recall that in mathematics a magma is a set with a binary operation on it. I am defining a magma typeclass in Haskell:

```
class Magma a where
    multiplication :: a -> a -> a
```

Of course lists of any type with concatenation operator form a magma, and indeed the following works in Haskell:

```
instance Magma [a] where
    multiplication x y = x ++ y
```

Similarly, real numbers with addition form a magma, but the following instance declaration does not work in Haskell:

```
instance (Num a) => Magma a where
    multiplication x y = x + y
```

Could you please explain me why the first instance declaration works perfectly well, while the second one with a type constraint does not work?
(I am using ghc.)

Comment: Note that if you add `UndecidableInstances` and `FlexibleInstances` language extensions then it works.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answers but could you please describe in a bit more detail which of the Haskell language mechanics prevents me (and why) from making such instance declarations? (Indeed it works with said language extensions, but why it doesn't work without them? I am interested in this for rather theoretical reasons, not practical ones.)

Comment: The problem is that instance declarations (by default) must be of the form `instance context => C (T a1 .. an)` where `a1` , .., `an` appear in `contentx` **and `T` is a type constructor**. In your case your declaration is of the form `instance context => C a` you are missing the `T`!

Comment: Suppose I add `instance Num [Int]` since I might like to perform pointwise operations (even if it is a bad idea for lists). Now, what should `multiplication [2] [3]` be? `[2,3]` or `[5]`? And what if I want a magma with `*` instead?

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks, it seems that your comment is *the* correct answer! So simply put the second declaration doesn't work because it is not syntactically correct! That type constructor "T" is needed. I think this is quite peculiar, since not writing a type constructor might be interpreted as a trivial "identity" constructor. Why such a design choice, why forcing to use a constructor? Bakuriu I like your comment/answer most, if you can add anything feel free to write down a proper answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you all for answers/comments as for now I think that Bakuriu's explanation is what I wanted to know. However thank you very much for giving me advice on *solving* that *obstacle* or suggesting means to deal with such cases in a proper way. As I am mainly interested in the *theoretical* (or rather *design philosophy*) reasons I find Bakuriu's explanation the most accurate for now. Nonetheless, I will wait and maybe someone can give reasons of why such a choice of the syntax of instance declaration have been chosen.

Comment: FWIW, you can replace `multiplication x y = x ++ y` with just `multiplication = (++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need [`FlexibleInstances`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleInstances) and [`UndecidableInstances`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/UndecidableInstances) language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Magma a where
    multiplication :: a -> a -> a

instance (Num a) => Magma a where
    multiplication x y = x + y
```

alternatively, use a new type:

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }

instance (Num a) => Magma (Sum a) where
    multiplication x y = Sum $ getSum x + getSum y
```

See [Edward Kmett answer why *the latter is a better approach.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216937/625914)

Also, note that your Magma type class has a lot in common with [`Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html), in particular your Num instance *under addition* overlaps with [Monoid instance for `Sum` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Monoid.html#Sum).

You may also define an instance for numeric types under multiplication as in [Monoid instance for `Product` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Monoid.html#Product).

Comment: +1 for the `newtype` and Kmett's advice. The first will require overlapping instances if other instances are needed later on (if they are not, just define `multiplication :: Num a => ...` and avoid the magma class). And overlapping instances are best to be avoided.

Comment: I think `multiplication x y = Sum $ getSum x + getSum y` can also be written `multiplication = liftA2 (+)`