# Guararantee an instance to have a certain function

Tags: haskell

My question is: How is it possible when declaring an instance to ensure that the data I'm declaring the instance for is guaranteed to implement a specific function?

Here's an example

```
   class AClass x where
     create :: String -> x

   data D1 = D1 { d1 :: String }

   data D2 = D2 { d2 :: String }

   instance AClass D1 where
     create s = if s == [] then D1 "D1Default" else D1 s

   instance AClass D2 where
     create s = if s == [] then D2 "D2Default" else D2 s
```

Now let's say in a real example this function is more complex than here but the same for all instances except for the default and the custom constructor.

So what I would like to be able to write is something like this:

```
    class AClass x where
      create :: String -> x

    data D1 = D1 { d1 :: String }

    data D2 = D2 { d2 :: String }

    class MyClass x where
      myDefault :: x
      myCustom :: String -> x

    instance (MyClass x) => AClass MyClass where
      create s = if s == [] then myDefault else myCustom s
```

Now I'm aware that this code has a bunch of problems. It should only demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

I also found this question ([How do I write, "if typeclass a, then a is also an instance of b by this definition."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213490/how-do-i-write-if-typeclass-a-then-a-is-also-an-instance-of-b-by-this-definit)) and I feel like it might provide a solution to my problem but I couldn't quite match its solution to what I'm looking for.

---- EDIT ----

So since the question seems to be confusing I'll try to put it differently:

Assume you have a library that uses a class *C*. You want to create multiple instances *I1*, ..., *In* for this class. These instances all have a function *f* whose implementation is almost identical for each *Ii* except for one string. Implmenting about 20 lines of code for each *f* results in a lot of code duplication which is what you're trying to avoid. So the question becomes: How do you create a single instance in a generic way so you then later only have to say "*I1* uses string 'Foo', "*I2* uses string 'Bar'" etc.?

I understand that this might be a bit vague, but I really don't know how else to describe my problem. I thought I was being clear in the upper paragraph.

Comment: Why do you have separate `AClass` and `MyClass` classes?

Comment: Because AClass comes from a library. I maybe should have mentioned that in the first place.

Comment: Do you want instances of `MyClass` to also be instances of `AClass`? Then you make `AClass` a superclass of `MyClass`: class AClass x => MyClass x where ...`.

Comment: Or, do you want to bulk-define instances for `AClass` for anything that is also an instance of `MyClass`? That, I think, you can't do, short of redefining `AClass` to use `MyClass` as its superclass.

Comment: What you're saying in the question doesn't make sense. Unlike in object-oriented languages like Java, data types don't "implement" functions in Haskell. You're going to need to be more specific, and not just assume that we'll get what you mean. Which function do you want to require? And why can't you just put it in the type class?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't assume you'll get what I mean. I thought I was clear. Let me try to rewrite it.

Comment: I don't see the problem with your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's sensible to introduce an extra class here. Why not just use a simple higher-order helper function:

```
createUsingDefault :: x -> (String -> x) -> String -> x
createUsingDefault def _ "" = def
createUsingDefault _ constr s = constr s

instance AClass D1 where
 create = createUsingDefault (D1 "D1Default") D1
instance AClass D2 where
 create = createUsingDefault (D2 "D2Default") D2
```

Or even

```
createUsingDefault :: String -> (String -> x) -> String -> x
createUsingDefault def constr "" = constr $ def++"Default"
createUsingDefault _ constr s = constr s

instance AClass D1 where
 create = createUsingDefault "D1" D1
instance AClass D2 where
 create = createUsingDefault "D2" D2
```

Comment: So first of all: Yes of course, this makes a ton of sense. Just one more question: How is D1 a valid argument for (String -> x)? I've not seen this before, but this is some basic stuff I'm assuming?

Comment: A constructor 'C' with parameters 'P_0', 'P_1', etc. for a data type 'T' has type: `C :: P_0 -> P_1 -> ... -> T`. Here, you have a constructor 'D1' with parameter 'String' for the data type 'D1', so its type is `D1 :: String -> D1`.